# Checkbox Specified Cast is not Valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating an empty data row to bind my grid view to, however, I'm always getting "The specified cast is not valid" error message for my Checkbox

This is my aspx :

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Include In Food Bag" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkBxIncludeInFoodBag" Checked='<%# Bind("IncludeInFoodBag") %>' ></asp:CheckBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkBxIncludeInFoodBag"></asp:CheckBox>
 </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my code behind:

```
protected void BindFoodBagItemsGridView()
    {
        DataTable FoodBagItems = BLFoodBagItem.GetAllFoodBagItems();

        if (FoodBagItems.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            FoodBagItemsGridView.DataSource = BLFoodBagItem.GetAllFoodBagItems();
        }
        else
        {
           tempFoodItems = new DataTable();
           tempFoodItems.Columns.Add("FoodBagItemId");
           tempFoodItems.Columns.Add("ItemName");
           tempFoodItems.Columns.Add("ItemQuantity");
           tempFoodItems.Columns.Add("IncludeInFoodBag");
            DataRow dr = tempFoodItems.NewRow();
            dr["IncludeInFoodBag"] = bool.Parse("false");
             -- I also tried dr["IncludeInFoodBag"] = false;
             -- I also tried dr["IncludeInFoodBag"] = 0;
            tempFoodItems.Rows.Add(dr);
            FoodBagItemsGridView.DataSource = tempFoodItems;

        }

        FoodBagItemsGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your column like this:-

```
tempFoodItems.Columns.Add("IncludeInFoodBag",typeof(bool));
```

You need add the datatype of column while adding it to DataTable.